# Version control (hg): can one directory be "synced" with different repositories?

Tags: emacs, git, version-control, hg

I have a directory for my work files which is under version control (Mercurial):

~/myfiles

In a subpath, I have a directory with Emacs packages for my org-mode setup:

~/myfiles/org-mode

As I said, the whole path is under version control and therefore "synced" with a Hg repository.
The original source for the `org-mode` subdirectory is also a (git) repository in the internet (http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/ ).

So it would be nice to be able to pull new versions of this directory directly from the official org-mode repository and then commit them to my personal repository to always have the version that works with my Emacs configuration.

*For a programmer, this might be a very easy question - as I'm not a programmer, I'm not sure how to handle that, but I assume it must be a common problem.*

Sure I could save the org-mode directory locally in another path and keep it out of my version control, but then I would not be able to restore the full working setup at a certain point of time easily.

Comment: Why do you need the org-mode files under hg? Are you working on them or are they global files that can be updated independently of your work?

Comment: my work is dependent on those files, because I often use features which do only work with the most recent version of org-mode and in case of problems I want to be able to easily go back to the last version that was working.

Comment: As far as I can see, there are no interoperability issues using both hg and git, as you explained. However, I would recommend that every time you pulled a change from the org-mode repo, you would also commit on hg (i.e. make the pull request a single change). Assuming that git stores everything it needs inside the org-mode folder, then rolling back from either hg or git would have the same effects.

Comment: thanks a lot! If you would turn your comment into an answer, I can accept it. But do I understand correctly: it only can work, as I am using 2 different VCS, so I could not do that with only `git` or `hg` to have several "overlapping" working directories synced to different repos?

Comment: I will turn my comments into an answer, but please refrain yourself from accepting it, as someone can appear in the meantime and develop a better answer. I don't use VCS extensively, so my knowledge may be flawed in some parts. As for your question in the last comment, there is no reason not to; if it works with git, it should work with hg.

Answer (score 1):

Using both *hg* and *git*, in the same tree, carries no inherent conflict; as those programs were developed independently, it stands to reason that they don't interfere with one another.

However, and in this case, *hg* superimposes itself upon *git* (another way to see it is that the *git* repository depends on the underlying *hg* directory structure). As such, consider the following example, where you already have *org-mode* cloned and there is a patch waiting to be pulled from the online repository.

This is what *hg* may look like before you pull the changes from *git*:

```
c:\myfiles> hg log -l 1
changeset:   123:da5f372c3901
tag:         tip
user:        John Doe <john@doe.com>
date:        Fri Jun 13 12:00:00 2014 -0500
summary:     Some change in the work files
```

You then pull the changes to the *org-mode* from *git*. What matters here most, though, is that the pull action doesn't *immediately* reflect to the *hg* repository.

You can test whether the newer *org-mode* patches work. If they don't work right off the box, you should run `hg revert --all`, which will restore the way the repository looked like at the time of the latest commit. If they do work or you don't find any problems, you *should* commit a change under *hg* reflecting that you pulled a set of changes to the *org-mode*.

```
c:\myfiles> hg com -m "Pulling changes in org-mode"

c:\myfiles> hg log -l 1
changeset:   124:da5f372c3901
tag:         tip
user:        John Doe <john@doe.com>
date:        Fri Jun 13 12:01:00 2014 -0500
summary:     Pulling changes in org-mode
```

If *git* stores its metadata regarding the repository under the *org-mode* folder (i.e. as *hg* does with the .hg folder in the repository's root), there shouldn't be a problem with rolling back the commit under *hg* (if by any chance you, after commiting, find that there is a problem with *org-mode*):

```
c:\myfiles> hg rollback
rolling back last transaction

c:\myfiles> hg log -l 1
changeset:   123:da5f372c3901
tag:         tip
user:        John Doe <john@doe.com>
date:        Fri Jun 13 12:01:00 2014 -0500
summary:     Some change in the work files
```

---

Also, as stated on my comments, you can do this regardless of whatever VCS software you run. If you have:

```
c:\my_repo
c:\my_repo\2nd_repo
```

There wouldn't be a problem, as in order to work with each repository, you would have to work whilst inside the directory where you are working.

<sup>[1](http://hginit.com) - I adapted some code from here because, as stated, I don't have much experience in the subject</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want org-mode to be a [subrepo](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository?action=show&redirect=subrepos). And it seems [git is supported](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository#Git_subrepositories) as a subrepo. The documentation is clear on what to do next:

```
echo "http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git" >> .hgsub
hg add .hgsub
git clone http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git org-mode
```

That'll let to track your stuff locally, and pull changes from orgmode when they are available.

Answer (score 0):

Your code depends on a 'vendor branch'. Each have their repository. No problem. Most version control systems allow an 'export' of the latest code, that is without metadata. If you commit that into your own repository then there is no collision. It is unlikely that you need to commit to both repositories. But if you need to, you can probably work it out. Search term: 'vendor branch'